# Codename One iOS Picker Style Error

Tags: ios, codenameone

I have a Problem with the Picker Component in my iOS Build.

[image: iOS Picker normal image]
[image: iOS Picker error image]
In the first Image you can see how the Picker normally looks like. In the second Image you can see the Picker has changes his size after it gets focused, but it should stay the same.

Here is my code for the Picker:

```
Picker pickFamilienstand = findPickFamilienstand(f);
pickFamilienstand.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
pickFamilienstand.setStrings("Familienstand","Ledig","Verheiratet");
pickFamilienstand.setText("Familienstand");
pickFamilienstand.setRenderingPrototype("Familienstand");
```

In the Codename One Designer I have added to component to a form and set its UIID. I have also customized the design via the Codename One Designer. I set the same Style in three Categories (Unselected, Selected and Pressed). On Android the Picker works fine.  I have two iOS devices with exactly the same behavior.

- iPhone 5s, iOS 8.1
- iPad

I don’t know which iPad I have, because I don’t have it on me right now. I will add this later.

Any Ideas why the Picker does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set the same style in the **disabled state** and now the picker works properly on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when margin isn't identical between the selected/unselected/pressed states triggering a resize on selection but with no revalidate the size doesn't go back.

You need to make sure to define padding/margin to identical values in all the states.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous post, I have set the same style for all three states (selected/unselected/pressed). I have check it again, they all have the same padding/margin. Any other ideas?

Comment: The higher ones are empty and the lower one is filled. Do you change things about the text field when you type into it? Did you mix TextField/TextArea who have different default UIID's?

Comment: The two above are two TextFields with the standard UIID Textfield. They also have the same style in the three states (selected/unselected/pressed). I do not change things about the Textfield, when i type into it and I also do not mix TextFields/TextAreas. In this Form there are only TextFields and Pickers.

Comment: I've been skimming too quickly and totally missed the fact that the last entry is a picker. A pickers core difference is that it's internally a button  so the main difference would be that it has a pressed state and uses the TextField UIID. Make sure to override the pressed state too (I know you said you did but this *has* to be the difference) and make sure the margin is identical in all 4 states.